# Is there a Java framework/assembly similar to the .NET Microsoft Enterprise Library?

Tags: java, .net, sql-server, oracle, enterprise-library

I'm looking for a Java assembly similar to the Enterprise Library assembly that Microsoft wrote, which includes a Cryptography, Database, Logging, Security, Validation and other application blocks that wrap around the .NET framework.  It's main purpose is to improve performance and to provide an API that makes it easier to build applications, so the application developer doesn't have to re-invent the wheel on the core libraries for doing common tasks.  I'm primarily looking for a nice assembly for connecting to Oracle and SQL Server (for databases), as well as the other application blocks that I mentioned above.  I am going to be building a bunch of reporting tools using a Java back-end and would like a jump start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Oracle and SQL Server, look for the JDBC drivers for each one ([SQL Server here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724) and [Oracle here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html)).

For cryptography, Java already comes with it bundled in, [click here for docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html).

For logging, there are many libraries:

- [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/)
- [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/)
- [Java logging API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html)

Security and validations are dependent on what kind of application you are using and there are many options other than the ones provided by Oracle itself, you need to provide more information what kind of app you are going to build so that people can provide better answers.

Also, most of the tools people use in the community **are not** provided by Oracle (this is a main difference between the Java and .Net ecosystem) so, you will find that there are many solutions on open source projects for the same problems and you will have to think, try and decide wich one of them to use.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're describing Java EE. See:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition
- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/index.html